# php error found unexpected T_STRING on line 1

Tags: php

found this error anyone help me..

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home/u231144272/public_html/includes/mbl.php on line 1

php full code here.....

```html
<?php
function mbl() { if ( empty($_GET['layoutType']) ) {
    if (empty($_SESSION['mobile'])) {
$user_agent = strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
if (preg_match('/android|avantgo|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino/i', $user_agent)
|| preg_match('/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|e\-|e\/|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(di|rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|xda(\-|2|g)|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i', substr($user_agent, 0, 4))){
return $_SESSION['mobile'] = 1;}else {
return $_SESSION['mobile'] = 0;}
}else{return $_SESSION['mobile']; }}else{$layoutType=$_GET['layoutType'];
$config='';
switch ($layoutType) {case "pc":
        $config = $_SESSION['mobile'] = 0;
        break;
        case "mobile":
        $config=$_SESSION['mobile'] = 1;}
return $config;}}
function samwatch($id,$width,$host){
    $emd=file_get_contents('http://www.server.juttlog.com/api.php?id='.$id.'&host='.$host.'');
if ($width){
$emd=  str_ireplace('width="100%"','width="'.$width.'"', $emd);}
return $emd;
}
function samdl($id){
    $jutt=file_get_contents('http://server.juttlog.com/video.php?videoid='.$id.'');
return $jutt;
}
function image($id,$wt){
    $link='http://server.juttlog.com/getimage.php?videoid='.$id.'&site='.$wt.'';
    return $link;
}
?>
```

Comment: The only thing on line 1 is `<?php`, that can't be the actual line number of the error.

Comment: did u check your first line for syntax errors

Comment: Often this error means a problem with the line before, because you left out a semicolon or close brace. But I don't see how that can be when the error is on line 1.

Comment: And where did you learn your horrible indenting style from? Please use an IDE that formats code readably.

Comment: I tested your code, I don't get any syntax errors.

Comment: which editor you are using? If notepad then change to Notepad++

Comment: I also agree with @user1844933 use a good text editor for php programming. open your php script in notepad++ and tell us what is the code in line 1

Comment: Maybe the problem is your line endings... Your local machine is running windows and your server is linux perhaps? Maybe this is the reason the server detect the problem in line 1. No line endings detected.

Comment: bro line 1 this... <?php

Comment: And line one as an EoL marker, too, on windows normally CRLF and on linux based systems LF only. That#s what @OmeCoatl is referring to ;)

Comment: check this http://sam927752.allalla.com/

Comment: Yeah, in your local machine, the code looks innofensive in line 1, but maybe the server interpret the code without the line feeds. resulting only 1 large line. [Check this](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_line_breaks)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I bet your problem is a line feed problem. Derivated of the different handling between windows (maybe your local machine) and the server (maybe linux/unix machine) and an FTP transfer.

In the server the code is interpreted as a unique single line, this explains why the error log shows "error in line 1" because only 1 line is visible to the server.

[this link](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_line_breaks) explains this behavior

[This tools](http://waterlan.home.xs4all.nl/dos2unix.html) can help you to solve the problem